# Data Binding onTouch in a layout

Tags: android, binding, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I changed my project to use Android Data Binding.

Everthing works fine except the `onTouchListener` on my custom `SectorImageView` which inherit `AppCompatImageView`. It has to be an `OnTouch` event instead of a `ClickListener` to handle x and y coordinates of the click.

As i implemented the Android Data Binding none of my listeners worked so i decided to use the XML approach.

**Question**

Is there any way to handle `onTouchListener` by simply adding an OnTouchListener to the class without using XML approach? Why the listener don't get recognized anymore when i implement the Android Data Binding?

Here is some code i tried to work with:

**Java code**

```
@BindingAdapter("app:onTouchListener")
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    // do something
}
```

**XML layout**

```
<x.y.z.SectorImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_sector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                app:onTouchListener="@{(view, event) -> onTouch(view, event)}"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/map" />
```

**Error**

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find method onTouch on ViewDataBinding
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

In `.java` file add like:

```
@BindingAdapter("touchListener")
public void setTouchListener(View self, boolean value){
    self.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            // Check if PRESSED
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                // code stuff
            }
            // Check if RELEASED
            else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                // code stuff
            }
            return false;
       }
    });
}
```

In `.xml` file add like:

```
<x.y.z.SectorImageView  app:touchListener="@{true}"}"/>
```

Comment: Indeed, this is working! I found this solution an another thread but i had problems with that. It's a little bit dirty because the method setTouchListener has to be static but it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Without declaring a static method `public void setTouchListener(View self, boolean value)` i get the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null in class ActivityBuffBindingImpl. A BindingAdapter in dev.dsomanager.view.component.SectorImageView is not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make all BindingAdapter methods static.`

Do you know how to handle that?

Comment: @MarcelI. am getting the same error without `static` `setTouchListener`. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I just added the static method and it worked fine for me. I couldn't find any better solution for this and hat to modify some variables to static to resolve this.